# How to map 2 unique column as 2 foreign key in child entity using hibernate annotation

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a query related to hibernate mappings. I have to map 2 unique column of a parent table as 2 foreign key in child entity using hibernate.

Ex -
Parent table -

```
CREATE TABLE TAB_PROD
(
    "TAB_PROD_ID"                    NUMBER(30,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,

    "PROD_GEN_ID"                    NUMBER(30,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,

    "TAB_PROD_GEN_ID"                NUMBER(30,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,

    CONSTRAINT "PK_TAB_PROD" PRIMARY KEY ("TAB_PROD_ID")

    CONSTRAINT "AK_TAB_PROD_GEN" UNIQUE ("PROD_GEN_ID", "TAB_PROD_GEN_ID")

)
```

Child table -

```
CREATE TABLE CHILD
(
    "CHILD_ID" NUMBER(30,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,

    "PROD_GEN_ID"                   NUMBER(30,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,

    "TAB_PROD_GEN_ID"               NUMBER(30,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,

    CONSTRAINT "FK_CHD" FOREIGN KEY ("PROD_GEN_ID", "TAB_PROD_GEN_ID") 
    REFERENCES TAB_PROD ("PROD_GEN_ID", "TAB_PROD_GEN_ID") ENABLE
)
```

These above are 2 table and `PROD_GEN_ID` and `TAB_PROD_GEN_ID` are reference key in child table.

Please help me to properly map in hibernate using Annotation.

Comment: you can use hibernate tools plugin for eclipse and generate the models using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

> TAB_PROD.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name="TAB_PROD")
public class TAB_PROD implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private BigDecimal TAB_PROD_ID;

    @Column (name = "PROD_GEN_ID", unique = true)
    private BigDecimal PROD_GEN_ID;

    @Column (name = "TAB_PROD_GEN_ID", unique = true)
    private BigDecimal TAB_PROD_GEN_ID;

    public BigDecimal getTAB_PROD_ID() {
        return TAB_PROD_ID;
    }

    public void setTAB_PROD_ID(BigDecimal TAB_PROD_ID) {
        this.TAB_PROD_ID = TAB_PROD_ID;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPROD_GEN_ID() {
        return PROD_GEN_ID;
    }

    public void setPROD_GEN_ID(BigDecimal PROD_GEN_ID) {
        this.PROD_GEN_ID = PROD_GEN_ID;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTAB_PROD_GEN_ID() {
        return TAB_PROD_GEN_ID;
    }

    public void setTAB_PROD_GEN_ID(BigDecimal TAB_PROD_GEN_ID) {
        this.TAB_PROD_GEN_ID = TAB_PROD_GEN_ID;
    }
}
```

> CHILD.java

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumns;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity(name="CHILD")
public class CHILD {
    @Id
    private BigDecimal CHILD_ID;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "PROD_GEN_ID", referencedColumnName = "PROD_GEN_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "TAB_PROD_GEN_ID", referencedColumnName = "TAB_PROD_GEN_ID")
    })
    private TAB_PROD tab_prod;

    public BigDecimal getCHILD_ID() {
        return CHILD_ID;
    }

    public void setCHILD_ID(BigDecimal CHILD_ID) {
        this.CHILD_ID = CHILD_ID;
    }

    public TAB_PROD getTab_prod() {
        return tab_prod;
    }

    public void setTab_prod(TAB_PROD tab_prod) {
        this.tab_prod = tab_prod;
    }
}
```

> Result

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `child`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `child` (
  `CHILD_ID` decimal(19,2) NOT NULL,
  `PROD_GEN_ID` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TAB_PROD_GEN_ID` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CHILD_ID`)
)

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tab_prod`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tab_prod` (
  `TAB_PROD_ID` decimal(19,2) NOT NULL,
  `PROD_GEN_ID` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TAB_PROD_GEN_ID` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TAB_PROD_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_iublvy229lc81t85wqlfgs0fm` (`PROD_GEN_ID`,`TAB_PROD_GEN_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_omdfd8sbm741v0yqiv4wist1t` (`PROD_GEN_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_3ox5nbcchj4wrjkyggrl7s01j` (`TAB_PROD_GEN_ID`)
)
```

Hope it works.

*If this isn't the desired result, then kindly let me know about it.*

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Just to clarify, in the table structure provided by you, in Child table these 2 columns are not mentioned as foreign key. But in my case, these 2 columns are already defined as foreign key in Child table and I have to create equivalent Child Entity class. Please help.

Comment: Hi @JyotiBalabantaray I tried to create Java POJO's with exact tables as described by you but it gave error namely `Hibernate configuration fails with message: Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key.` I tried it in MySQL and PostGRE but same error. Maybe its a database issue. Can you please specify that which database you're using. A facility is provided by both netbeans and eclipse which helps us to generate POJO classes from table structures. You can try it yourself or just contact me if there's any issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"TAB_PROD_ID","TAB_PROD_GEN_ID"})})

public class TabProd{
...